# looping through json and passing the data as a variable to a method inside a loop

Tags: javascript

I have a small json

```
var StoreJSON = [
    {
        "Store_ID": "46305",
        "inv_list_id": "list-46305-inventory"
    },
    {
        "Store_ID": "48760",
        "inv_list_id": "list-9980-inventory"
    },
    {
        "Store_ID": "48811",
        "inv_list_id": "list-46305-inventory"
    },
    {
        "Store_ID": "53046",
        "inv_list_id": "list-1272-inventory"
    }
]
```

I am trying to loop through it and then retrieve content for each 'list-46305-inventory'

I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong with my loop.

```
var strInvID = new Array();
var invList = '';
var record = '';

for(var i = 0; i<= StoreJSON.length; i++){
    strInvID[i]= StoreJSON[i].inv_list_id;

    invList = ProductInventoryMgr.getInventoryList(strInvID[i]); // retriving the list
    record += invList.getRecord(26551826); // getting the product record
}


document.write(record);
```

//
ProductInventoryMgr.getInventoryList() is a custom java method which returns the content inside the list

//
Problem: the loop is stopping at the first position. I am getting the output from the first inv_list_id but its not giving me all the others

Let me know I need to add more clarification to the question.

'26551826' is a product ID which is present in all those lists

Comment: Your code should work as is, the only problem could be in one or both of the functions `getInventoryList` and `getRecord`.

Comment: @ecampver--actually when I am passing the values manually into the getInventoryList()..it works fine. So that made me think that I might have the loop wrong

Comment: Probably it is typo, but I think there shall be `i < StoreJSON.length`, not `<=`. It may cause problems on last iteration.